# How do I fill a hole above my shower where cockroaches are coming through?

Tags: repair, bathroom, shower, ceiling, hole

I recently moved into an old brownstone and realized that there is a cockroach issue in the entire building. I'm working on getting rid of them but the other night I noticed some were near the ceiling above my shower.

There is a pipe in the corner of the shower that is a couple inches thick and runs up to the ceiling. Where it connects to the ceiling there is a large gap on all sides. I want to seal it.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions? I was told steel wool and expandable foam, but want to know if that is sensible to do right above the shower where it is likely to be humid.

Comment: What kind of pipe is it, drain, water, radiator?

Comment: It appears to be a water pipe, here is a picture. It runs from the ledge above the spout all the way to the ceiling in the corner. I personally have never seen any exposed plumbing like this before until I moved here so I am not entirely sure...

Comment: [IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2i7bwh5.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: To extend on @BMitch 's question, does it get overly hot, or cold, or condensate on the outside? May be as easy as just slapping some spackle or caulk in there.

Comment: The pipe itself gets wet whenever the shower is on and definitely has condensation on it. Unfortunately this building is so old that there is zero ventilation in the entire bathroom so condensation runs rampant unless we leave the door open and use a floor fan to disperse the air from the bathroom to the rest of the house.

Comment: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/4jn9jq.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding foam such as Great Stuff would work fine.

Comment: A can of spray foam would definitely do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Silicone caulk would probably work the best with moisture and temp changes.  You need to figure out how to push it up on the back side.

Comment: This was my plan until I noticed that the hole behind the back of the pipe is significantly larger. Should I caulk the front and do something different in the back?

Comment: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/4jn9jq.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: I would add spackle or drywall mud to reduce size of hole and then silicone.

Comment: Caulk is not a good choice if filling an open gap of more than 1/2 inch (13 mm).  A structural material like plaster, quick setting foam, etc. is needed.